# What is this cheap critter?

Tags: riddle, music

I am the cheapest of the flying animals,
As such I cannot give any change.
I guess I am just riffing yeah yeah,
But I heard my creator is "too too wise".

Anyways I will just soar above, won't I,
Oh oh oh oh, you realize I must go.
My stay has been sugary, but bye.
I will just soar above, won't I?

Hint 1:

> My brother is a man least complex, 
>  As well as a day lost to the breeze.

Hint 2:

> There is a 100% chance that the title is misleading. Some regrets about that.

Hint 3:

> See revised less misleading title

Hint 4:

> Riffing is a musical term, tag added.

Comment: Is the answer "A human who flies on Southwest?" =P

Comment: Or Ryan Air really, dunno why but I thought of that right away too xD

Comment: Just to clarify: it IS an animal, right?

Comment: Part of the answer is a word that refers to animals.  It is not a specific creature. I regret the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not confident (edit: I'm pretty confident after writing the answer), but it's close enough to try.

> **Free Bird**, the song by Lynyrd Skynyrd 
>  Some of these are lyrics references, the yeah yeah and Oh oh oh oh inspired this answer.

I am the cheapest of the flying animals,
As such I cannot give any change.

> "'cause I'm as free as a bird now, and this bird you cannot change"

I guess I am just riffing yeah yeah,

> He sings "yeah yeah" after a few different lines to my recollection. Perhaps also right at the solo.

But I heard my creator is "too too wise".

> No idea. Either a reference to "Lord" in the song or the band (creator) Lynyrd Skynyrd? The song *is* legendary.

Anyways I will just soar above, won't I,
Oh oh oh oh, you realize I must go.

> "Won't you fly high, free bird" and some "oh"s in the verses.

My stay has been sugary, but bye.

> "Bye, bye, baby. It's been a sweet love."

VERY late edit: I heard the opening credits of Happy Gilmore this weekend, which instantly reminded me that I never responded to the riddle's hints.

My brother is a man least complex

> Another song by Lynyrd Skynyrd is **Simple Man**

As well as a day lost to the breeze

> The chorus of **Tuesday's Gone** is "Tuesday's gone with the wind"

Comment: "My brother is a man least complex" is definitely referencing Simple Man, so I'm sure you've got it.

Comment: too too wise is actually two two y's, for lynyrd skynyrd,

Comment: How crafty! Bravo! I must say, it's the littlest things that can change a riddle's difficulty. The quotes on "too too wise" had me convinced it wasn't Free Bird, so I let it sit on Friday. Saw the riddle lasted the weekend and gave it a shot. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think this may be a reference to

> representations of hummingbirds in the Nazca lines.

The phrase "just riffing" could refer to

> humming (instead of singing a proper song),

while the reference that 'my creator is "too too wise"' could refer to the fact that

> many of these images are not apparent from the ground (the creator therefore being wiser than people who are earthbound),

and related to the quote 'I will just soar above'

> since the images are visible from the air.

'you realize I must go' could refer to

> concerns over damage to the images, such as that caused by a Greenpeace publicity stunt,

while 'My stay has been sugary' could be a reference to

> the hummingbird's diet, typically of sugar-rich nectar.

Comment: To be honest, I am not familiar enough with that to make a riddle about it. But wow put some good thought into that.

Comment: the too cheap part could also refer to the hummingbird spending HUGE amounts of energy to 'hover'. The speed at which it needs to flap its wings is so high that the hummingbird is literally always dying of hunger. Look it up on wiki :) -basically It could all be pointing to it having no time to stay or to waste energy etc...

Answer (score 2):

Since it is not an animal per se, I was thinking it could be

> Modest Mouse

I am the cheapest of the flying animals,
As such I cannot give any change.

> makes me think of cheap people bumming rides and a mouse gets rides from birds in a way. I can't think of a better description for that at the moment

I guess I am just riffing yeah yeah,
But I heard my creator is "too too wise".

> too too wise makes me think of owls and owls eat mice

Anyways I will just soar above, won't I,
Oh oh oh oh, you realize I must go.

> A mouse will soar above as an owl carries it away

My stay has been sugary, but bye.
I will just soar above, won't I?

> A mouse could be living in a sugar cain field, and the incorrect assumption, it's going to get eaten, that it will just soar above makes me think of a modest mouse

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this at all, and I lack the time to ponder this riddle (sorry!)

I guess it could be

> Any kind of paper wasp
> They obviously like sugar, and the name 'paper' wasp because they have hives made out papery stuff. If your house is made of paper you're pretty poor/cheap or you have one hell of a kind of paper. The riffing could refer to the buzzing a wasp makes when flying. I don't get the creator line though...   Anyway, good riddle and good luck to others

Comment: Nope, I like the thought though.

Comment: I find that downvote somewhat uncalled for ...    this is an answer that is both explained and to the point. Just because I said I dont think its the right answer and dont have time to find another atm does not warrant it + most of the time on puzzling exchange - attempts are encouraged to inspire and help others finding their own answers.